# System.BadImageFormatException with c# net-core

Tags: c#

We try to setup  obfuscar for a .NET5 project for three distro's, Windows, Linux and OSX. These distro's are created in VS2019 with the publish options .. self-contained and single-file
For the Windows distro this creates an .exe that packs all the required assemblies in it. Unfortunately, obfuscar errors with System.BadImageFormatException Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid. It then details regarding 'Mono.Cecil.PE'
The latter is understandable because a NET5 project is not supposed to run with Mono !

Maybe I overlooked some setting in the obfuscar.xml ? Or maybe obfuscating the published executables of a .NET5 project with obfuscar is not the right way to do it .. ?